# Why can't I display emoji on Pebble using Symbola font?

Tags: c, emoji, pebble-watch

I added the [Symbola font](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) to my watch app, and tried to display some emoji on the Pebble, but alas, no dice.

Here's the relevant vars and functions in my code… be gentle, I'm kind of a C n00b.

Is this even the proper way to format unicode for a C string? I added the colons just as separators.

```
static char emoji_chars[]=":\xF0\x9F\x98\x81:\xF0\x9F\x98\x93:";

void handle_init(AppContextRef ctx) {
  (void)ctx;

  window_init(&window, "Window Name");
  window_stack_push(&window, true /* Animated */);
  text_layer_init(&emoji_layer, GRect(30, 30, 150, 50));
  text_layer_set_background_color(&emoji_layer, GColorWhite);
  text_layer_set_text_color(&emoji_layer, GColorBlack);
  text_layer_set_font(&emoji_layer, fonts_load_custom_font(resource_get_handle(RESOURCE_ID_SYMBOLA_24)));
  text_layer_set_text(&emoji_layer, emoji_chars);
  layer_add_child(&window.layer, &emoji_layer.layer);
}

void pbl_main(void *params) {
  resource_init_current_app(&APP_RESOURCES);
  PebbleAppHandlers handlers = {
    .init_handler = &handle_init
  };
  app_event_loop(params, &handlers);
}
```

Comment: Does it work with "regular" (i.e. not-UTF-8) text, such as "hello world"?

Comment: @Jongware yes it works with regular text… in fact, it displays just the colons ":::" on the screen but not the emoji characters

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://developer.getpebble.com/sdkref/group___text_layer.html) says on the argument of `text_layer_set_text`

> The new text to set onto the TextLayer. This must be a null-terminated and valid UTF-8 string!

(note the exclamation point). "Unicode" is not a valid C string encoding, but "UTF-8" is. Inserting your icons' Unicode values as UTF-8 characters should work.

**Edit**

Hold on -- you already encoded the character U+1F601 as UTF-8. And it *is* a valid character in your font, according to http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/Symbola.pdf.

Comment: Right, that's why I chose this font. Does this confirm that I did in fact encode the emoji/unicode chars correctly in the char array?

Comment: @FelixanderWeber: yes, as far as I can see you did. I think you have try go back to trying with a simple text and a standard font, and work your way up from there. If that all works, it could be something in this particular font that makes it not work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you in the font resource manifest specified those emoji characters in the characterRegex?

I also see that there is a patch for fontgen.py to include unicode here That may assist you.

https://github.com/fisakov/pebble-sdk-characterRegex